# Trying to convert Date and Time String to ISO Date and Time String in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime-format

I am getting following String for date and time from the Database `20180309220001` 
I am trying to convert this DateTime String to the following pattern-
Target Pattern `2016-10-06T00:00:00-04:00`

To achieve the above pattern I have written following java method

```
 public static String dateConvertorISO(String dateAndTimeStamp) {
        try {
            LocalDateTime originalLocalDateTimeStamp = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTimeStamp,
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
            ZoneId usEastern = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
            return ZonedDateTime.of(originalLocalDateTimeStamp, usEastern).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot convert date-time: {} to ISO because {}", dateAndTimeStamp, e.getMessage());
        }
        return dateAndTimeStamp;

    }
```

But I am not able to match the pattern, above given method, is returning following -
`2018-03-09T22:00:01-05:00[America/New_York]`

- *Target pattern is an example and not the actual conversion of the given Date and Time String*

Comment: I am in America/New_York

Comment: but to be on safer side I am specifying ZoneId as well

Comment: Can't you just replace `toString()` with `format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)`? I guess that new answer confirms my suspicions :)

Comment: To me it makes perfect sense that `20180309220001` becomes `2018-03-09T22:00:01-05:00[America/New_York]`. What result did you want instead? If you don’t want `[America/New_York]`, convert to `OffsetDateTime` using `ZonedDateTime.toOffsetDateTime()`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `toString()` use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format()`:

```
    public static String dateConvertorISO(String dateAndTimeStamp) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime originalLocalDateTimeStamp = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTimeStamp,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
        ZoneId usEastern = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(originalLocalDateTimeStamp, usEastern);
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(zonedDateTime);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Cannot convert date-time: {} to ISO because {}", dateAndTimeStamp, e.getMessage());
    }
    return dateAndTimeStamp;
}
```

Comment: This the new method -public static String dateConvertorISO(String dateAndTimeStamp) {
        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.of(
                    LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTimeStamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")),
                    ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot convert date-time: {} to ISO because {}", dateAndTimeStamp, e.getMessage());
        }
        return dateAndTimeStamp;

    }

Comment: Upvoted. It’s a matter of taste, I would probably use `return ZonedDateTime.of(originalLocalDateTimeStamp, usEastern).toOffsetDateTime().toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to remove time zone from end:

```
public static void main(String... iArgs)
{
    Calendar vCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    Date vDate = vCalendar.getTime();

    ZoneId usEastern =ZoneId.of("US/Eastern");

    ZoneId amNY = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

    System.out.println(vDate.toInstant().atZone(amNY));
    //prints 2018-04-12T14:38:46.519-04:00[America/New_York]

    System.out.println(vDate.toInstant().atZone(usEastern));
    //prints 2018-04-12T14:38:46.519-04:00[US/Eastern]

    DateTimeFormatter noTimeZoneFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(vDate.toInstant().atZone(usEastern).format(noTimeZoneFormatter));

    System.out.println(vDate.toInstant().atZone(amNY).format(noTimeZoneFormatter));

    //prints 2018-04-12T14:38:46
}
```

Comment: This has taken me much closer to the target pattern ZonedDateTime.of(originalLocalDateTimeStamp, usEastern)
                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ")).toString()

Comment: You’re over-complicating things. And when using the modern date and time classes like `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`, there is no need to bring in the outdated and poorly designed `Calendar` and `Date`. The modern classes give you all the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and nudge in the right direction, I have updated my method to following and now I am getting the desired date and time pattern.

```
 public static String dateConvertorISO(String dateAndTimeStamp) {
        try {
            return ZonedDateTime.of(
                    LocalDateTime.parse(dateAndTimeStamp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")),
                    ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot convert date-time: {} to ISO because {}", dateAndTimeStamp, e.getMessage());
        }
        return dateAndTimeStamp;

    }
```